# WP Super Cache compression not working

Tags: plugin-wp-supercache

I have WP Super Cache installed, and compression is turned on.

However, both [GIDZipTest](http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php) and [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights) Chrome extension say that compression is not enabled.

I added the following to my .htaccess file, and they still say compression is not enabled:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

**UPDATE**: I have since disabled WP Super Cache, and I'm testing W3 Total Cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

W3 Total Cache is working; compression is being performed correctly.